# Происхождение слова "царь"

Tags: этимология

Общепринято считать, что слово *царь* произошло от от лат. *Caesar* — цезарь.
Однако, в этимологическом словаре крупнейшего  лингвиста  М. Фасмера высказываются на  этот счет сомнения, но  без попытки иного  обоснования.

Возможно, слово *царь* происходит от *TERRA* (lat), *ȚARA* — *цара* (ароман) — земля, страна?

https://dexonline.ro/definitie/%C5%A3ar%C4%83

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос. Вы можете воспользоваться формой ответа ниже, чтобы попытаться дать ответ на свой же вопрос — это не запрещено. Тогда другие участники получат возможность дать свой ответ и оценить Ваш по достоинству.

Comment: Простите, а Фасмер стал российским лингвистом на тех же основаниях, по которым в слове _Цезарь_ появился корень _ра_?

Comment: Уточнение - М. Фасмер, российского происхождения, член-корреспондент АН СССР. Ну а *ра* как и в слове *ра-дуга*, как и в индоарийском * Tara* /цара/.

Comment: «Буква Ц (Ț) в данном слове означает - Правитель.» ===== Буква Ц в любом слове — это буква Ц. Но главное — вопрос надо править, оставив только первые три строки.

Comment: Это какой-то театр абсурда. Аскер дает ссылку на некий словарь румынского(!) языка, где разбирается происхождение румынского слова ȚÁRĂ, от латинского слова terra и называет это мнением Фасмера по поводу русского слова царь. Я не силен в румынском, но насколько могу судить, ни царь, ни тем более Фасмер там даже не поминается.

Answer (score 5):

У Черных происхождению слова ***царь*** посвящена большая статья. В русском языке оно известно с XV века, но часто писалось с титлом ц(с)рь, поэтому нет особых сомнений в том, что  ***царь*** происходит от ***цъсарь.***

**Цезарь — прозвище Юлия Цезаря**, только позже оно стало титулом римских императоров. Форма ***цъсарь*** была широко распространена на славянской почве, от готского Kaizar, которое также восходит к раннелатинскому Caezar.

Что является не абсолютно ясным, так это **латинское происхождение этого слова** (в этом случае предполагается, что оно означает или *густые кудри*, или происходит от глагола *рубить, рассекать*). Сомнения основаны на том, что  **ранняя форма  Kaizar встречается в Новом завете.**

Comment: Да, и царя Соломона умершего до Рождества Христова не было и слов у русского народа до ХV века тоже не было :)

Comment: Не могу понять, что вас огорчает. В ХV  веке слово "царь" было зафиксировано в русских письменных источниках со значением  "властитель, государь".  Ранее (в XIII  веке) этим титулом иногда называли крымского хана. Вы не доверяете Черных? Вы можете доказать, что это не так?

Comment: Огорчает лишь то, что согласно "лингвистам" народы тысячелетиями были немыми, то и дело занимались поиском слов в других странах и континентах дабы выразить свои мысли, дать наименование тому или иному предмету или явлению. Вместо того, чтобы сквозь дебри письменности и исскуственно созданных языков, искать "начальные" истоки общего праязыка.

Comment: Салмансар, Навуходоносор(ссар), Валтасар(Белшацар) и сколько их ассирийских и прочих царей...И в слове Цезарь, и в слове Кайзер есть этот самый цар, сар.

Answer (score 2):

> Однако, даже в этимологическом словаре крупнейшего российского лингвиста М.Фасмера высказывается на этот чет обоснованные сомнения, но увы без попытки иного обоснования.

Не совсем понятно, о каких сомнениях Вы говорите. В словаре М.Фасмера под сомнения ставится не само происхождение, а цепочка восхождения от латинского. И даже в этом смысле не такие уж там большие сомнения.

Что касается возможных альтернативных вариантов, то "народная этимология" имеет очень богатый арсенал методов этимологических исследований. Слово **РА** играет в этой "науке" едва ли не ключевую роль.

Comment: "неправильно составленная цепочка восхождения от латинского" - это и есть ошибочная трактовка происхождения слова. Ни за какие уши *царь* из *цезаря* или *кайзера* не вытащишь. :)

Comment: См. словарь М.Фасмера. Никакой неправильной цепочки там нет.